# Including Part Template within a Custom Module

Tags: theming, 8

I am writing a custom module that uses several twig templates in my modules /templates directory. I want to use part templates (https://www.drupal.org/node/2634166) so that I could reference the following:

```
{% include directory ~ 'includes/spr_table_selectors.twig' %}
```

The problem is my include keeps referencing my main site theme (themes/mytheme/...). Is there an easy way I can reference my includes directory within my custom module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a change to the theming documentation in this case. Namespace for twig is always set to `MYTHEME/templates` or `MYMODULE/templates`.

The `directory` variable is to `ACTIVETHEME/templates`.

So if you look at how the Symphony folks have been do things, you will find out they have their template parts in a subdirectory named `parts` rather then a sibling directory named `includes`. Use the subdirectory will fixed your problem. **BONUS** you can use `@` to call the namespace of your module or theme like this:

```
<header>
  {% include '@MYMODULE/parts/header.html.twig' %}
</header>
```

Remember to keep your template part name(s) unique from the templates in use by your Drupal install to avoid them being used as a full template item that overrides something provided by core or another module.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for the clarification!